# OpenCV - finding translation of rigid body point clould

Tags: opencv

I have 2 images sourceImg, refImg.

I've extracted the features like so:

```
cv::GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector detector;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> sourceKeyPoints, refKeyPoints;
detector.detect(sourceImg, sourceKeyPoints);
detector.detect(refImg, refKeyPoints);
```

I want to find the translation of an object from refImg to sourceImg. There is no rotation or perspective change, only simple 2d translation. There may be some noise.

findHomography() works fine when both sets have the same number of features extracted, even handling noise quite well.

My question is, what do I do when the number of features differs?

Can someone point me in the right direction regarding DescriptorExtractor and Matching?

Note: I can't use SURF/SIFT for patent reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `FlannBasedMatcher`class from [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?highlight=flannbasedmatcher#flannbasedmatcher). Use this to match descriptors (of any type) and then use the best matches to find your homography.

Comment: This is useful, thank you. Are there any guidelines for which feature extractors work best with which descriptors?

Comment: @BillWilliamson Typically the method of feature detection/extraction is related to method of descriptor computation so I would advise you to use the corresponding descriptor for any given extractor (i.e. compute SIFT descriptors at features selected using the SIFT detector). Alternatively, if you meant to ask about which **matching** technique to use with each descriptor I wouldn't be able to help you unfortunately.